# String text to byte array Java - RSA

Tags: java, python, encryption, type-conversion, rsa

I have an RSA encryption system for securing the communication between a Server (Python) and a Client (Java). Currently, I manage to encrypt and decrypt correctly information from the client to the server using the server's keys. What I am not able to do, is to decrypt the message on the Client (Java) that comes from the Server (Python).

The encryption snippet in `Python` is the following:

```
publicKeyStr = None
with open(PATH_KEY, 'r') as file:
    publicKeyStr = file.read()

publicKeyClient = RSA.importKey(publicKeyStr)
encryptor = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
message = encryptor.encrypt(plainMessage)

# Message's length is always 128 bytes on the server side
#Send message to the client (RabbitMQ)
```

The variable `message` with the ciphered content is received on the Client side in String format and here comes the problem: the decryption method in Java expects a `byte[]` input and a maximum block size of 128 bytes, but when transforming the String `message` to a `byte[]` array, these String has over 128 bytes. This was my approach on the client side (Java):

```
public String call(String queue, byte[] message) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    final String corrId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    String replyQueueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
    AMQP.BasicProperties props = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
            .correlationId(corrId).replyTo(replyQueueName).build();

    channel.basicPublish("", queue, props, message);

    final BlockingQueue<String> response = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1);

    String ctag = channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true,
            new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
                @Override
                public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                                           Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                           byte[] body) throws IOException {
                    if (properties.getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
                        response.offer(new String(body, "UTF-8"));
                    }
                }
            });

    String result = response.take();
    channel.basicCancel(ctag);
    return result;
}

public static String sendElement(String topic, byte[] message) {
    SendRabbitMQ sendRabbitMQ = null;
    String response = "";
    try {
        sendRabbitMQ = new SendRabbitMQ();
        response = sendRabbitMQ.call(topic, message);
    } catch (IOException | TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (sendRabbitMQ != null) {
            try {
                sendRabbitMQ.close();
            } catch (IOException _ignore) {
            }
        }
    }

    return response;
}

String response = SendRabbitMQ.sendElement("topic", encryptedInfo);
byte [] responseByte = response.getBytes();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
System.out.println(new String(cipher.doFinal(message)));
```

The error raises when `responseByte` is assigned, as it's size is over 128 characters.

**Therefore, my question is**, how can I transform the message String sent from the server side on the client size in order to correctly transform this String to a byte[] array?

**EDIT**: I believe it does not have to do with the RabbitMQ code on the client side, but just in case, I have included the methods used.

Comment: You need to include the part that converts the binary encrypted message into text format. It's probably something like hex or base64. The reverse needs to be done on the Java side.

Comment: Actually, it's part of the RabbitMQ code, but I'll include it anyways.

Comment: Yes, I did not express myself correctly, the error raises when running doFinal line (javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 128 bytes), but the cause of the flaw is the incorrect parsing of responseByte, which has a length over 128 bytes (while I have checked that the server does send 128 bytes).

Comment: Why did you decide that the body received from the MQ is in UTF-8? It appears the data is sent in binary. Why do you define a queue of `String` if you receive the message already in `byte[]`?

Comment: Well you are absolutely right, that does not have sense at all. I have modified the code to directly retrieve body variable and now works fine. Thank you very much!